# Can American citizens legally patronize Pyongyang (restaurant chain)?

Tags: united-states, international

Can American citizens legally patronize [Pyongyang (restaurant chain)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyongyang_(restaurant_chain))?

I am aware that, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tourism_in_North_Korea#Restrictions_and_warnings:

> In July 2017, the U.S. government announced that American citizens would no longer be permitted to visit North Korea as tourists. The travel ban took effect on September 1, 2017.

but I don't know whether the U.S. government prohibit  American citizens from frequenting businesses owned by North Korean entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prohibition is against using a regular US passport to enter North Korea (you can [apply for a special passport](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/KoreaDemocraticPeoplesRepublicof.html)): or you can use a non-US passport. There is no prohibition against patronizing a North Korean business, be it in North Korea or elsewhere.